# How display notifications on checkout page [PRESTASHOP 1.7]

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I need to check show an error notification on checkout page (not cart) after the user inserts a shipping address. It should be handled on OrderController. but I am not sure where. Which method should be overridden and how to show error notification?

[image: prestashop 1.7 checkout step]